# How to create vertical "panels" for hosting controls in an asp.net web page?

Tags: asp.net, razor, web-controls, html-table, asp.net-webpages

I need to create vertical strips on both sides of a web page to house/host controls (comboboxes, checkboxes, or their asp.net equivalents, and the like). These two strips (somewhat akin to an Outlook bar) need to be bounded by a small banner/header at the top and a small footer (at the bottom, naturally); the vast middle section will be comprised of a Bing Map component.

How does one go about doing this? With an html table, somewhat like a WPF Grid? Or...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally layout of sections would use divs as containers and CSS for positioning
The following points to a page that lists a number of CSS frameworks that could be considered for a possible solution. http://speckyboy.com/2011/01/10/15-lightweight-and-minimal-css-frameworks/